# Are questions from the perspective of freelancing *customers* on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-topic

On Freelancing, can I ask questions that are not from the perspective of a freelancer, but rather from the prospective customer of a freelancer?  For example, would it be on-topic to ask for a website recommendation where I would seek to hire a freelancer?  Specifically, would the following question be welcome?

> **Looking for a web application that brings handymen etc. and their customers together**
>
> I'm looking for a web application where customers can review the work of handymen, painters, cleaners, plumbers, electricians, carpenters, etc.: anyone performing manual labour for others for a fee. On the web platform I envision, the handyman (etc.) advertises their services, and customers can review and rate their work. Perhaps it also includes a service where customers can post a request and handymen can bid to carry this out. What Tripadvisor and Kayak are for hotels, what Urbanspoon is for restaurants, and what Yelp is for businesses in general.
>
> I am aware of [werkspot](https://www.werkspot.nl), but this is only for The Netherlands. My existing approach is to look at craigslist/kijiji/gumtree or whatever the localised equivalent is, but searching for a particular service will yield many results with no way of systematically estimating previous customer satisfaction.
>
> Can anyone recommend a web application according to my description?

Would this be on-topic on Freelancing?

Answer (score 4):

Not currently, and that is not likely to change. It is essentially asking for either a list of answers, or for the opinion of what-would-be-the-best option. This type of question is not usually allowed on most of the SE sites, for their openness in answers. You can certainly ask on Chat though for recommendations, as there is not hard-lined topic there.